# Filtering data in datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables

I have a datatable and I want to filter data according to search (input), by drop down list (select) or by date range:

[image]

I can filter using "Search" But I want to filter using Customer drop down list or date range using "Initial Date" and "Final Date" then press "Filter" button, I've got two files :
index_customer.php then I call from ajax (datatable) fetch_customers.php file for filtering.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="well">
          <header class="header_part">
          <h2 class="text-center">Detailed List</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="row well input-daterange">
          
          <div class="col-sm-4"><label> <span>Customer</span> </label>
                <select id="customer_name" name="customer_name"  class="form-control" onchange="showname(this)" required>
                    <option selected disabled value=""> - Select Customer - </option>
                    <?php include("config/fetch_name.php") ?>
                </select>
            </div>  
          
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label> <span>Initial Day</span> </label>
              <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="initial_date" id="initial_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" style="height: 40px;"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label> <span>Final Date</span> </label>
              <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="final_date" id="final_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" style="height: 40px;"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" name="filter" id="filter" style="margin-top: 30px">
                <i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Filter
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 text-danger" id="error_log"></div>
          </div>

          <br/><br/>
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="order_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Customer</th>
       <th>Order Item</th>
       <th>Order Date</th>
       <th>Order Value</th>
       <th>Exchange USD</th>
       <th>Paid</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
     <tfoot>
      <tr>
       <th colspan="3">Total</th>
       <th id="total_order"></th>      
       <th ></th>
       <th id="total_pago"></th>
      </tr>
     </tfoot>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
   </div>
  </div>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
 </body>
</html>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
   var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({
       dom: 'Blfrtip',
      buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
          ],
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "Todos"] ],
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
    url:"fetch_customers.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: function ( d ) {
        d.customer_name = $('#customer_name').val();
        d.initial_date = $('#initial_date').val();
        d.final_date = $('#final_date').val();
    }
},
    drawCallback:function(settings)
    {
    $('#total_order').html(settings.json.total);
    $('#total_pago').html(settings.json.total_pago);
    }
   });

    
  
 });
      $("#filter").click(function(){
        var initial_date = $("#initial_date").val();
        var final_date = $("#final_date").val();
        var customer_name = $("#customer_name").val();

        if(initial_date == '' && final_date == ''){
          $('#order_data').DataTable().destroy();
          load_data("", "", customer_name); // filter immortalize only
        }else{
          var date1 = new Date(initial_date);
          var date2 = new Date(final_date);
          var diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
          var diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

          if(initial_date == '' || final_date == ''){
              $("#error_log").html("Warning: You must select both (start and end) date.</span>");
          }else{
            if(date1 > date2){
                $("#error_log").html("Warning: End date should be greater then start date.");
            }else{
               $("#error_log").html(""); 
               $('#order_data').DataTable().destroy();
               load_data(initial_date, final_date, customer_name);
            }
          }
        }
      });

      $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        todayBtn:'linked',
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        autoclose: true
      });
 
</script>
```

This fetch_customers.php file (where I want to filter info), I can filter using "Search":

```
  <?php
    
    
    $initial_date = $_REQUEST['initial_date'];
    $final_date = $_REQUEST['final_date'];
    $customer_name = $_REQUEST['customer_name'];
    
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "mysq1passw0rd");
    
    $column = array('order_customer_name', 'order_item', 'order_date', 'order_value',  'tasa_usd', 'pago'  );
    
    
    
    $query = '
    SELECT * FROM tbl_order 
    WHERE order_customer_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
    OR order_item LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
    OR order_date LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
    OR order_value LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
    OR tasa_usd  LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
    
    ';
    
    if(isset($_POST["order"]))
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
    }
    else
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY order_id ASC ';
    }
    
    $query1 = '';
    
    if($_POST["length"] != -1)
    {
     $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }
    
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    
    $statement->execute();
    
    $number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();
    
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);
    
    $statement->execute();
    
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    
    $data = array();
    
    $total_order = 0;
    $total_pago = 0;
    
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
     $sub_array = array();
     $sub_array[] = $row["order_customer_name"];
     $sub_array[] = $row["order_item"];
     $sub_array[] = $row["order_date"];
     $sub_array[] = $row["order_value"];
     $sub_array[] = $row["tasa_usd"];
     $sub_array[] = number_format($row["pago"], 2, ",", ".");
     
      //$sub_array[] = number_format($row["monto"], 2, ",", ".");
     
    
     $total_order = $total_order + floatval($row["order_value"]);
     $total_pago = $total_pago + floatval($row["pago"]);
     $data[] = $sub_array;
    }
    
    function count_all_data($connect)
    {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order";
     $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     return $statement->rowCount();
    }
    
    $output = array(
     'draw'    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
     'recordsTotal'  => count_all_data($connect),
     'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
     'data'    => $data,
     'total'    => number_format($total_order, 2,',','.'),
    // 'total_pago'    => number_format($total_pago, 2)
     'total_pago'    => number_format($total_pago, 2,",",".")
    // 'total_pago'    =>  number_format($total_pago, 2, ",", ".");
    );
    
    echo json_encode($output);
    
    
    ?>
```

I tried with this code in fetch_customers.php for filtering, but I recieve and error message:

```
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))

{
    
    $query = '

WHERE order_customer_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_item LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_date LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_value LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR tasa_usd  LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 

';

    
}else{

$query = '

WHERE order_date = $initial_date

';

}
```

Please anyideas?